# CSS3 Animation for moving a ball

Tags: html, css, animation

I want to move a move a ball with a image inside from left to right and back again. While it moves it must bounce and move. I can't make this happen. Any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <img src= "F:\New folder\1.jpg" />
   <img src="F:\New folder\2.jpg" />
   <img src="F:\New folder\3.jpg" />
   <img src="F:\New folder\4.jpg"/>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
img
{
   width:30px;
   height:30px;
   border-style:solid;
   border-width:3px;
   border-radius:50%; 
   animation: spin 3s infinite linear  alternate , bounce 2s 1 forward , movement 5s 3s  1 ;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
0% {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
16% {
    top: 190px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
32% {
    top: 50px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
48% {
    top: 190px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
62% {
    top: 100px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
78% {
    top: 190px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
90% {
    top: 150px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
}
100% {
    top: 190px;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
     }
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@-webkit-keyframes movement {
 0% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    }
 33% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 25%;
    }
 66% {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    }
  100% {
    top: 0%;
    left: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax was incorrect; you cannot set multiple animations like that.

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), the syntax for an animation is as follows:

```
<single-animation-name> || <time> || <timing-function> || <time> || <single-animation-iteration-count> || <single-animation-direction> || <single-animation-fill-mode>
```

Additionally, you currently need to use the `-webkit` prefix for the animation to work in Chrome/Safari.

**For the bouncing animation** -- [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yZyaa/)

In order for this animation to work, you would need to set `position:relative` on the element since you are using positioning in the keyframes.

```
.ball {
    position:relative;
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
```

It's also worth noting that you can combine keyframe properties like this:

```
@keyframes bounce {
    16%, 48%, 78%, 100% {
        top: 190px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
}
```

**For the spinning animation** -- [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fK473/)

Use `linear` for the timing-function. This will allow for a smooth animation.

```
.ball {
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
```

It's worth mentioning that you can exclude `0%` from the keyframe in this instance:

```
@keyframes spin {
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

**For the movement animation** -- [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/t96rr/)

If the element is positioned to begin with, it won't need a value for `0%` in the keyframe.

```
.ball {
    animation: movement 3s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: movement 3s linear infinite;
    left:0;
}
```

The keyframe is therefore pretty simple in this instance:

```
@keyframes movement {
    100% {
        left:100%;
    }
}
```

---

**Combined animations** -- [**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TWF2B/)

If you want all the animations to occur at the same time, simply combine the keyframes.

```
@keyframes combined {
    16%, 48%, 78%  {
        top: 190px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    }
    32% {
        top: 50px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    62% {
        top: 100px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    90% {
        top: 150px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
        top: 190px;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out;
        left:100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry , it works . what if i want to move back the balls from right to left

Comment: Thank you JoshC . and i want to bounce only alternate balls. any idea ?

Comment: I want to move all the balls , but bounce only 2nd and 4th ball

Comment: @Josch C . I want the balls to bounce up and the one that don't bounce isn't rotating

Answer (score 0):

You should also correct your movement code for coming the ball back is

```
@-webkit-keyframes movement {
  0% {
    left: 0%;
  }
  50% {
    left: 100%; /* for moving right */
  }
  100% {
    left: 0%; /* for moving back or left */
  }
}
```